# Return table with foreach not echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a word press plugin using short code.
I have a array like this:

```
$data = array(
0 => array('name' => 'Jonh', 'birth' => 1985, 'number' => 6),
1 => array('name' => 'Marry', 'birth' => 1991, 'number' => 10),
2 => array(same above),
3 => array(same above)
.......................
);
```

How can I use foreach loop or any ways to return (not echo) a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Birth</th>
<th>Number</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Show $data[0]['name']</td>
<td>Show $data[0]['birth']</td>
<td>Show $data[0]['number']</td>
</tr>

<tr>
Show all keys and all values of $data same above into each <tr> tags
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you wanna try using `print_r($data)`?

Comment: I am a newbie php. I don't really understand how print_r working.  I only need to return my table. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the best way is to put your table inside var and create it row by row, like this :

`

```
$data = array(
0 => array('name' => 'Jonh', 'birth' => 1985, 'number' => 6),
1 => array('name' => 'Marry', 'birth' => 1991, 'number' => 10)
);

$myTable = "
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Birth</th>
<th>Number</th>
</tr>";

foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    $myTable .= "
    <td>Show ".$value['name']."</td>
    <td>Show ".$value['birth']."</td>
    <td>Show ".$value['number']."</td>
    </tr>";

}
$myTable.="</table>";

echo $myTable; //You can also return it
```

`

Comment: Nice! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
$data = array(
0 => array('name' => 'Jonh', 'birth' => 1985, 'number' => 6),
1 => array('name' => 'Marry', 'birth' => 1991, 'number' => 10),
2 => array(same above),
3 => array(same above)
);
$str="<table><tr>";
$str.="<th>Name</th>";
$str.="<th>Birth</th>";
$str.="<th>Number</th></tr>";


foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    # code...
    $str.="<tr>";
    $str.="<td>Show $data['name']</td>";
    $str.="<td>Show $data['birth']</td>";
    $str.="<td>Show $data['number']</td></tr>";
}
return $str;
```